# Creating n random points and creating quadrilaterals (stuck) C

Tags: c

I have this homework assignment and I am a bit stuck with it.

> Create n random points, using these points create 2 quadrilaterals, which envelop the rest of the points, and compare the area of the 2 shapes.(not a graphical solution, purely mathematical)

I can not figure out how to connect my points or how to tell the computer which points to connect.  I was thinking maybe finding the max and min X and Y could work but I didn't get further than that.

Thanks is advance!

```
void genp(int n,int** x,int** y);
void rectangle(int n,int** x,int** y);
void file(int n, int** x, int** y);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Please specify number of points!\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *x;
    int *y;
    genp(n,&x,&y);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d]=%d\ty[%d]=%d\n", i, x[i], i, y[i]);
    }
    rectangle(n,&x,&y);
    file(n,&x,&y);
    free(x);
    free(y);
    return 0;
}

void genp(int n,int** x, int** y)
{
    int r;
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    *x = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    *y = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        r = rand();
        (*x)[i] = r;
        r = rand();
        (*y)[i] = r;
    }
}

void rectangle(int n,int** x,int **y)
{
    int maxlocx,maxlocy,maxx,maxy,minx,miny,minlocx,minlocy;
    int zerox=*x[0];
    int zeroy=*y[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if ((*x)[i]>zerox)
        {
            maxx=(*x)[i];
            maxlocx=i;
        }
        if ((*y)[i]>zeroy)
        {
            maxy=(*y)[i];
            maxlocy=i;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if ((*x)[i]<zerox)
        {
            minx=(*x)[i];
            minlocx=i;
        }
        if ((*y)[i]<zeroy)
        {
            miny=(*y)[i];
            minlocy=i;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe max x:%d, corresponding y:%d\n",maxx,(*y)[maxlocx]);
    printf("\nThe max y:%d, corresponding x:%d\n",maxy,(*x)[maxlocy]);
    printf("\nThe min x:%d, corresponding y:%d\n",minx,(*y)[minlocx]);
    printf("\nThe min y:%d, corresponding x:%d\n",miny,(*x)[minlocy]);

    int area=
}

void file(int n,int** x,int** y)
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("data.txt","w");
    fprintf(f,"n=%d\n",n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fprintf(f,"%d,%d\n",(*x)[i],(*y)[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: "how to connect my points" is both vague and broad. The "computer" doesn't need to connect the points. You just need some sort of data structure that stores the right data to represent the shape. For example, you can have a list of ordered  x,y coordniates. There are many other ways. Or perhaps you are asking how to find the points of the two quadrilaterals in the first place. Please clarify your question - it is too unclear.

Comment: Although your program does not need to produce graphical output, working a couple of graphical examples by hand might give you some insight into how your program could select points.

Comment: Having thought a bit about the problem myself, however, I see no reason to believe that there is *any* way to choose points from among your random set to serve as vertices of two quadrilaterals that either individually or jointly cover all the remaining points.  If you have reason to think differently then presumably you have been presented an algorithm for making the selection, or at least a theorem whose proof could provide insight on how to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwers! Unfortunately no algorithm was given by the teacher, or theorem for that matter.

Comment: I only have to learn C coding for one semester, so we didn't really have the time to go too deep with things, and therefore i don't know many things about the c language, sometimes (like now) even the logic as to how solve certain problems is a great challenge for me. Can you please elaborate your ideas a bit more?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Well, as far as I can see, nowhere does the assignment require the vertices of the quadrilaterals to be from the set of points. You could use an axis-aligned bounding box, for example.

Comment: If the vertices of the quadrilaterals have to be from the set of points then it's impossible (or at least not guaranteed to be possible). Consider 100 points spaced evenly around the circumference of a circle for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking maybe finding the max and min X and Y could work but I didn't get further than that.

This sounds about right for me and was the first thing that I thought when reading that problem statement.

[image]

As for the 2nd quadrilateral maybe you could do something like trying to find a bounding rectangle with tilted axis instead of axis that are parellel to the X and Y axis. For example, with a tilt of 45 degrees the bounding box would look like this:

[image]

> I can not figure out how to connect my points or how to tell the computer which points to connect.

I'm kind of getting the impression that you are trying to find the [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converx_Hull) of your set of points. That would be a much harder problem than just finding a bounding box. (And it might not be a quadrilateral anyway)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, thanks to you i managed to get somewhere with my project (unfortunately not a complete solution) but good enough to pass.